# Trying to make integration with PayPal for Visa and MasterCard

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, asp.net-core-3.0, mastercard

I trying to make integration with PayPal to set visa and master card online payment in egypt and other countries,
So if i maked it

1 i do need business account in PayPal
2 and follow documents
3 Never save customer card detail in db only a viewmodel
That's all i think

When someone makes a payment with visa or MasterCard will pay for my paypal accounts if it's successed i can receive on my account in egypt?

Is that video a good documentation
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DBuA8Cq2mWOI&ved=2ahUKEwiWi8_tzf3oAhX2aRUIHT1-BpwQjjgwA3oECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3q2HqcAoXincuerS1SFYUA&cshid=1587612866019

and how to make the transaction amount goes to two accounts
Such as Admin & designer

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to integrate PayPal, but I would not suggest using a 2-year-old Youtube video as a reference point.

I would suggest looking at Smart Payment Buttons for the front-end.

- Here is the front-end version that would call routes on your server to create and then capture a v2/order: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server . Note the fetch calls to '/demo...' placeholders, which must be replaced with actual routes to server-side code of yours which will call the v2/orders PayPal APIs.
- Here is an alternate simpler, client-side-only version that does not call your server for order creation and capture, and instead is HTML/JS only:  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: At first thanks for your comment, i will try it with PayPal api if i got a trouble cause it's first time for me i will contact you again .. thanks again